# SQL Server: How to update all the keys inside an json array

Tags: json, sql-server, json-query

I have a query like (simplified):

```
SELECT 
    JSON_QUERY(r.SerializedData, '$.Values') AS [Values] 
FROM 
    <TABLE> r 
WHERE ...
```

The result is like this:

```
{ "201902":121, "201903":134, "201904":513 }
```

How can I change this in SQL to:

```
{ "2019-02-01":121, "2019-03-01":134, "2019-04-01":513 }
```

Meaning after the year (4 digits) add an '-' and end the key with  '-01'.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL2017 and later, you could use the example of [renaming a key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#example---rename-a-key)
(which might be a bit cumbersome and might not work properly in case of duplicate keys)

```
declare @j1 nvarchar(max);
select @j1 = N'{"201902":121, "201902":145, "201903":134, "201904":513}';

select @j1 as before;

select @j1 = JSON_MODIFY(JSON_MODIFY(@j1, concat('$."', left(a.[key], 4), '-', right(a.[key], 2), '-01"'), CAST(a.value AS int)), concat('$."', a.[key], '"'), null)
from openjson(@j1) as a;

select @j1 as after, isjson(@j1);
```

Or handle json as a string with a simple REPLACE()

```
declare @j2 nvarchar(max);
select @j2 = N'{"201902":121, "201902":145, "201903":134, "201904":513}';

select @j2 as before;

select @j2 = replace(@j2, a.[key], concat(left(a.[key], 4), '-', right(a.[key], 2), '-', '01'))
--if keys appear as values...
--replace(@j2, concat('"', a.[key], '"'), concat('"', stuff(a.[key],5, 0, '-'), '-01"'))
from openjson(@j2) as a;

select @j2 as after, isjson(@j2);
```